# How long does it take to add 1 lb. of refrigerant to an air conditioning unit?

Tags: hvac, cooling

My HVAC unit was running but not cooling properly. I called an HVAC guy who came to check. He came without a scale and told me he can fill the refrigerant and tell me how much he filled by just telling me the pressure.

After just about 5 minutes he told me he filled 1 lb. Did i got ripped off? How long does it take to add 1 lb? What is the best way to find how much did he add? is it possible to measure this by just looking at pressure gauges?

Comment: Wouldn't he know how many pounds he came with and how many he left with? He should know that way.

Comment: Question says no scale. Of course, if the HVAC guy didn't find and fix the leak, it will need filled again...

Comment: Somehow I missed the no-scale. I would guess that he could know that given typical conditions going from X psi to Y psi means there were so many pounds out of the system. Still, doesn't seem too outlandish to approximate it.

Comment: That is a total crock! You can tell of your system is full based on pressure and temp but there is no way to tell how much was added without a scale. You could have gotten more than 1LB or less.

Comment: Was it R22 or R410A?

Comment: It's not like HVAC guys sell the stuff by the ounce.  Is your AC cooling now? If so, I'd say he did you right except for the fact that you probably still have a leak.

Comment: R22 but i think i got my answer, guy without a scale kick don't let him touch my HVAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds about right. It usually takes 5-15 minutes for me to fill 1 lb.